# Complex number such that affixes of itself, its squared and its cube form a right triangle. $z,z^2,z^3$ form a right triangle in argand plane

Tags: complex-numbers

$\DeclareMathOperator{\aff}{Aff}$
Here is a funny problem  I stumbled upon recently

I call the **affix of a complex number** the corresponding point in the argand plane, that is

$$\aff(\mathrm{i})=(0;1)$$

Find all $z \in \mathbf{C}$ such that the affixes of $z,z^2\ \& \ z^3$ form a right triangle.

I decided to Set $A=\aff(z),B=\aff(z^2),C=\aff(z^3)$

I have proven that :

1. If $z$ is a solution, then $z\neq 0,\  z\neq 1, \ \& \ z\neq-1$
2. If the triangle is right angled at A, $z$ must be a non zero imaginary number.
3. If the triangle is rigth angled at B, $\aff(z)$ has to lie on the vertical line defined by $x=(-1)$, except for $z=(-1)$.

(I'll post my proof when I get some time to write it in $\mathrm{\LaTeX}$ soon.)

I'm down to the third case : I have proven that if the triangle is right angled at $C$, then :
$$\Re \left(\frac{1+z}{z}\right)=0$$

Thanks to some experimentation, I know that $\aff(z)$ should lie on the circle centered at $(-\frac12;0)$ with radius $\frac12$, with $z$ again respecting the first condition above.

Now,how do I prove this ?

Thanks for the help.

Here is an animation.

[image: Third case]

Comment: The use of the word affix is uncommon, i think it's because is outdated, and this may confuse some readers. In the modern use of complex numbers one simply think the complex numbers as points in the complex plane.

Comment: yes, I am well-aware, but I have to teach it as it is a mandatory term in french exams, so I stuck to the old vocabulary.

Comment: I first come across the term "affix" maybe a week or so ago (I'm born-and-raised in the US), but now I seem to be noticing it more on Math.SE. (["Frequency illusion"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_illusion), I suppose.) Interestingly, a site search reveals sporadic uses here going back a decade. I'm surprised I'd never picked up on it in all that time. ... Anyway, I appreciate the context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh dear,

It turns out I'm too tired to think, I found the following :
let's set $z=a+ib$ as in the question

then :
$$\frac{z+1}{z}=\frac{(a+1)+ib}{a+ib}=\frac{(a+1)+ib)(a-ib)}{a^2+b^2}$$
From which one gets
$$\frac{z+1}{z}=\frac{a+a^2+b^2-ib}{a^2+b^2}=\frac{a+a^2+b^2}{a^2+b^2}-\frac{ib}{a^2+b^2}$$

now, because this is an imaginary number we get
$$C(a,b)=a+a^2+b^2=0$$
which is the equation of an ellipse because it is a polynomial of two variables, of degree two. We see that there is no division, therefore, this is the equation of a circle

Let's rewrite it to see the circle's centre and radius :
$$C(a,b)=a+a^2+(b-0)^2$$
That is with two canonical forms
$$C(a,b)=\left(a+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+(b-0)^2-\frac14=0$$
But then we get
$$\left(a-\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)^2+(b-0)^2=\frac14$$
We just need a square after the equal sign to get the radius
$$\left(a-\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)^2+(b-0)^2=\left(\frac12\right)^2$$

which is the equation of the circle mentioned in the question / OP.

Please note however that $(-1)$ and $0$ both belong to this circle.

Answer (score 1):

Partial Solution:

If $z=\cos t+i\sin t,$

$$m_{AB}=\dfrac{\sin2t-\sin t}{\cos 2t-\cos t}=-\cot\dfrac{3t}2\text{ if }\sin\dfrac t2\ne0$$

Similarly,
$$ m_{BC}=-\cot\dfrac{5t}2, m_{CA}=-\cot2t$$

Now we need at exactly one of the products $m_{AB}\cdot m_{BC},m_{BC}\cdot m_{CA},m_{CA}\cdot m_{AB}$  to be $=-1$

Answer (score 1):

HINT

Angle between vectors $\vec{KM}, \vec{LM},$ where the points have complex coordinates $z_K, z_L, z_M,$ is equal to
$$\arg{\frac{z_M-z_L}{z_M-z_K}}.$$
In the present exercise we want

$$\arg{\frac{z-z^2}{z-z^3}}=\frac{\pi}{2}+k\pi,\;k\in \mathbb{Z}$$
or
$$\arg{\frac{z^2-z}{z^2-z^3}}=\frac{\pi}{2}+k\pi,\;k\in \mathbb{Z}$$
or
$$\arg{\frac{z^3-z^2}{z^3-z}}=\frac{\pi}{2}+k\pi,\;k\in \mathbb{Z}$$

Comment: yes this is exactly what is written there : if the real part is zero, the argument is +-pi/2 
you forgot the minus sign  :)

Comment: moreover it's easier to justify saying it's an imaginary number, because if there's an inverse (which happens here), the justification is trivial.

Comment: I did not forgotten the sign. My $k$ in $\frac{\pi}{2}+k\pi$ can be negative.

Comment: yes I saw the Z after writing my comment sry